# How to make a connection for data exchange with a PLC? I/O

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tcp, plc

I have been asked to do data exchange with a plc, I suppose I am serious about TCP / IP protocol but I am new to this, the question is simple, I just want to send and receive data from a PLC

Comment: We will need to know which make and model of PLC and maybe the firmware release. I am out-of-date with PLCs; in my day they implemented proprietary protocols and maybe something standard such as Modbus. It may be that you can now program your own server software into them. The easiest way might be to buy a Modbus(or whatever) library for your PC. But we can't tell you what your options are without knowing which PLC you are trying to talk to, and what you need to do to the data on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Richard Urwin mentioned in his comment, more information on your system would help to isolate a specific answer.

In short, though, an OPC server would be your best bet. These software packages can read and write data from a PLC, and push that data to other software (SQL databases, SCADA systems, custom written software, etc.)

An OPC package that I use often (and is usually branded as "more than just an OPC") is KepServerEX, by Kepware. It can communicate with virtually any PLC on the market, on a wide variety of network protocols (including Ethernet, as you would be using for TCP/IP). A quick Google search will provide information more specific to whatever your needs are.